# Does Mac/IOS use the same sys/socket.h as the Linux kernel?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, sockets

I am going to be porting the 39dll libraries to Linux. This lib has been ported to Mac and IOS already and i was wondering if the sys/socket.h stuff needs to be re-written. You can find the libs in question [HERE](http://www.vetragames.com/Stuff/39dylib/39dylibsource.zip) and [HERE](http://www.host-a.net/dl/0/19773928711358)

Does anyone know? Ive done some google searching and looked at sever of the "suggested" articles to no avail. Some article suggested that it "might" work, but i need a more definitive answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you asking if the content of Mac OS X's `<sys/socket.h>` is identical to Linux's version? No, Mac OS X's header is based on the BSD's.

**>** <kbd>man socket</kbd>

> ```
> SOCKET(2)                   BSD System Calls Manual                  SOCKET(2)
>
> NAME
>      socket -- create an endpoint for communication
>
> SYNOPSIS
>      #include <sys/socket.h>
>
>      int
>      socket(int domain, int type, int protocol);
>
> DESCRIPTION
>      Socket() creates an endpoint for communication and returns a descriptor.
>
>      The domain parameter specifies a communications domain within which com-
> ```

If you're asking if there's source code compatibility between the two platforms, then yes, as long as the source code sticks to portable interfaces.

If you're thinking of some other reason that the sockets stuff might need to be rewritten, I guess that depends on whether or not your current code meets your requirements when built for OS X.

Comment: Is that text from the linux MAN pages or from OSX?

Comment: That's odd, because the snippet you show here is almost verbatim of the man socket in Linux. Does that mean that i may not need to change the implementation between the two as long as my code calls the socket in this way?

Comment: @nterry The answer to that is covered under 'source code compatibliity' in my answer. Are you aware of the POSIX standard? Even though OS X and Linux are different implementations, they both implement POSIX, so as long as you stick to the POSIX interface it should work with both platforms.

Comment: Yes, i am aware of POSIX. I was just making sure that i understood completely before implementing.