# Xamarin and c++ code

Tags: c#, android, c++, xamarin.android, xamarin

Currently I`m exploring how to write mobile apps for Android using Xamarin and C#. Also I have some c++ libraries(and source code for them) that should be used in application. These libraries are responsible for communication via internet(just to say).

So it is possible to use this c++ code in xamarin.android project? Or it should be rewritten in c# to be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im not sure with networking but most C++ code can be used 100% in Xamarin.

If it works, you can't be sure if it works correctly in every situation on IOS.
We had the same problem with using UDP Sockets for VOIP(C#).
Most of the time it will work, but in case of VOIP you need to use iOS sockets so you can set them to a special mode so they won't be closed when the app gets paused.

So it depends on what you want to do and how the C++ code is written.
Im not sure if you can use normal unix sockets when using C++ on iOS but that should be the only problem when using it.

Just checked: [Does Mac/IOS use the same sys/socket.h as the Linux kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11197015/does-mac-ios-use-the-same-sys-socket-h-as-the-linux-kernel)

I think, if your library uses BSD sockets everything should be fine.

Comment: Sorry, bro, for not accepting the answer for so long. Somehow it got lost.

Comment: Do you have NDK sample to refer on?

Answer (score 1):

Usually it is possible to call some code in any other library unless

1. It exports the functionality
2. There is a wrapper in your language to make use of that exported functionality.

I do not know much about this Xamarin thing but I guess you should see if the library is binary compatible not code (i.e) that compiles with the source of your C++ project and you can make calls to it from your C# program.

Also while checking the Zamarin library documents, it seems that not every piece of C# code can be used on Xamarin platform. Please check the Xamarin community and the forums for more in details.

Comment: usually, yes. And we have a C# project(WinForms) that use wrappers to call these libraries. But is it possible in Xamarin to do so as well?